# ExtJS 4.2.2 How to clear the previous chosen item in a Combobox?

Tags: extjs

I have a Combobox that when I choose an item, it creates me a textarea with the fieldLabel name as the item chosen. The problem is that I don't know how to clear the Combobox when an item is selected.
this is the code of the combobox

[image]

and this is the listener where I want to create the textarea and delete the item chosen where it is created

[image]

and this the code of the function which creates the textarea

enter image description here

Comment: Have you tried [clearValue](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.3/#!/api/Ext.form.field.ComboBox-method-clearValue) or [reset](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.3/#!/api/Ext.form.field.Text-method-reset)?

Comment: Yes, I've tried both of them but it's not working!!

Comment: You should get rid of **forceSelection: true** config, because when it's set combo reverts to last selected value when record can't be found in the store. Another solution may be to clear lastSelection value of the combo (set it to null or empty string) before you clear the value

Answer (score 0):

To clear the value of combobox on selection , you can use select event of combo like this:

```
xtype:'combo',
listeners:{
        'select':function(combo){
           combo.setValue("");
        }
    }
```

Comment: I put the  select listener like this and it's not working:
{       .....
          listeners:{
            'select':function(combo){
           combo.setValue("");
        },
            'click': function() {
              var combo  = Ext.getCmp('utile_selectt_combo');
              var index  = combo.getValue();
              var valeur = combo.getRawValue();
              var panel = Ext.getCmp('panel_add_textarea');  
              if(valeur!==''){
              ....                    
             }              
            }
} }

Comment: Where have you put this listener? This should be in combobox config.

Comment: Yes, in combobox confif. I put it inside the listeners of the combobox.

Comment: Can you create a fiddle for your problem statement.

Comment: Thank you for your help and sorry for late. I found the solution. I had to add the function initComponent() for my view.